# Load array values on textbox

Tags: vba, outlook

That code is used to attach files, each file i attach(select) get one new position in filepath(). And in my form i have 8 textbox(invisible by default). What im trying to do is, when filepath(1) is filled(by the attach), textbox1 becomes visible, when filepath(2) is filled(by the attach) textbox2 becomes visible.
.
.
.
.

My code:

```
    Dim filepath() As String 

    Private Sub CommandButton4_Click() 

        Const msoFileDialogOpen = 1 
        Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject") 
        Set objWord = CreateObject("Word.Application") 
        Set WshShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell") 
        strInitialPath = WshShell.ExpandEnvironmentStrings("%USERPROFILE%") & "\Desktop\" 
        objWord.ChangeFileOpenDirectory (strInitialPath) 
        With objWord.FileDialog(msoFileDialogOpen) 
            .Title = "Select the file to process" 
            .AllowMultiSelect = True 
            .Filters.Clear 
            .Filters.Add "All Files", "*.*" 
            .Filters.Add "Excel Files", "*.xls;*.xlsx" 
            .Filters.Add "Text Files", "*.txt" 
            .Filters.Add "Various Files", "*.xls;*.doc;*.vbs" 
            If .Show = -1 Then 

                Dim filePath() As Variant
Dim myFile As Variant
Dim num As Integer: num = 1
'On Error Resume Next
'num = UBound(filepath)
'On Error GoTo 0


'### Redim this array as a base-1 array
ReDim Preserve filePath(num To .SelectedItems.Count)

'### I made some revisions here:
For Each file In .SelectedItems
    Set objFile = fso.GetFile(file)
    filePath(num) = file  'Store a string, rather than an object.
    Me.Controls("TextBox" & num).value = file
    num = num + 1
Next
            Else 

            End If 

        End With 

    End Sub
```

Thanks,

Comment: I don't see any reference to `TextBox1`, `TextBox2`, etc., in this code. Nor do I see any initialized/declared Variant/Array variables.  Can you please clarify, revising your question as needed?

Comment: That code is used to attach files, each file i (select) attach get 1 position in filepath(). And i my form i have 8 textbox(invisible by default). What im trying to do is, when filepath(1) is filled, textbox1 becomes visible, when filepath(2) is filled textbox2 becomes visible.

Comment: Where is `filepath` declared? As your code is currently written, without more context, `Ubound(filepath)` should raise a Type 13 Mismatch error which you are suppressing with an ill-advised `On Error Resume Next` handler.

Comment: filepath is declared as "Dim filepath() As String "

Comment: Not in the code you have provided above.  You `ReDim` it, which is fine. But then why are you trying to get the `Ubound` of an undeclared variable?

Comment: Then i have "Dim num As Integer 
            On Error Resume Next 
            num = UBound(filepath) "

Comment: Can you answer a question?  I'm asking *why* you're attempting to obtain the `Ubound(filepath)` before `filepath` is dimensioned? That's a waste of three lines of code that will *always* raise an error.

Comment: But i dont recive any error :o
Im not sure why is that done!
i'm picking this code from a mate, im just trying to complete the code and the program.

Comment: Get rid of `On Error Resume Next` and I guarantee you get an error.

Comment: Yeah i got an error :C

Comment: Can u help me to simplify and make this works correctly?

Comment: Yes that is what I'm trying to do... Please see my answer below. I have not tested this but I believe it should work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have undeclared variables in your code and a totally unnecessary use of `On Error Resume Next` where you attempt to get the `Ubound(filePath)` before you instantiate `filePath` as an array.

**GET RID OF THESE LINES:**

```
'        On Error Resume Next 
'        num = UBound(filepath) 
'        On Error Goto 0 )
```

You should declare your variables properly. Your user form **must contain textbox controls** named like `TextBox1`, `TextBox2`, ... `TextBox8`.

```
Dim filePath() as Variant
Dim myFile as Variant
Dim num As Integer: num = 1 

'### Redim this array as a base-1 array
Redim Preserve filepath(num to .SelectedItems.Count) 

'### I made some revisions here:
For Each file In .SelectedItems 
    Set objFile = fso.GetFile(file) 
    filepath(num) = file  'Store a string, rather than an object.   
    Me.Controls("TextBox" & num).Value = file
    num = num + 1 
Next 
TextBox14.Text = num & (" - Ficheiro(s) Adicionado(s)")
```

Code is working and displays 6 different selections in an example file that I created:

[image]

Comment: Num = 1 and File = (location from the file that i have selected) c:\Users\<username>\desktop\file.txt

Comment: That error raises because your form does not contain an object control named `TextBox1`.

Comment: I change is working now!
But, only shows for the 1st text box, the next files attached does not appear in the respective textbox

Comment: Can you upload a screenshot to imgur.com and share the link to the image file? When I test this, it works. Did you remember to make each textbox `.Visible = True`?

Comment: They are all visible, Screenshot from what? the code or the form?

Comment: The form. Also, please update your original Q to include the code you are now currently using.

Comment: What is happening, is that values only change on the 1st textbox :c, i guess that is because "num" is always equals to 1

Comment: `num` is *not* always equal to 1. It starts with a value of one, and then inside the `For/Next` loop, it increases each time, `num = num + 1`.  You should try to step through your code, put a breakpoint at that `For` statement, and use F8 to step through the code line-by-line. Perhaps that will help you identify what is happening. But the code that you are currently using works as expected for me, printing different file path to each textbox.

Comment: You will want to look for, what is the value of `.SelectedItems.Count`, and examine the `filePath` array variable in the Locals window within the VBE.

Comment: Filepath always have just Filepath(1).

Comment: Then it seems that `.SelectedItems.Count = 1` (since we `ReDim filePath(num to .SelectedItems.Count)`, which suggests that you have only selected 1 item from the FileDialog.

Comment: I only select 1 file!

Comment: Well if you only select 1 file, it will only populate 1 textbox. If you select 8 files, it will populate all 8 textboxes. If you select 9 or more files, it will probably raise an error.

Comment: Hann,, it works if i select multiple files, but if i don't, it doesn't works, If i want to select file by file how can i do?

Comment: What do you mean "it doesn't work"?  What do you *want* it to do if you only select one file?

Comment: It doesn't work if i have to pick different files from different locations.

Comment: Do you understand how a loop works?  I suggest attempting to revise your loop(s). Post a **new** question if you have trouble.    I will suggest that what you need to do is use a single-select FileDialog in its own loop (e.g., `For i = 1 to 8...` display the picker, then add the value to the array and populate each textbox. Also FYI unless you are doing something with `objFile` variable, get rid of that, it's totally unnecessary in the code you have currently posted.